# Define variables and corresponding values from the results of a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, variables, pdo

I have a table which stores for a given user,  both a variable name and its corresponding value.  Each user may have different number of variables,  or say different number of rows.

```
id_user | var_name  |  var_value
-------------------------------
 1      | $a        |   1
 1      | $b        |   6
 2      | $a        |   7
 3      | $c        |   4
 4      | $a        |   1
```

I'm querying the table and indeed get the set of values per user,  looping through the array I get for user_id 1,

```
$a    1
$b    6
```

That's OK but I need to set variables and itś values like this:

```
$a=1
$b=6
```

Have tried to use

```
echo $var[0]."=".$var[1];
```

in order to get $a=1,  but the variable is not set,  just printed.
Tried variable variables

```
$$user_var=$var[0]; #then variables $a and $b are created
$$user_var=$var[1]; #hoping to assign second column value to each variable.
```

None of these seem to work.  Indeed tried a third approach,  concatenating in mysql,   and get these result per row:

```
$a=1
$b=6
```

Again how do I set **PHP** variables as this:

```
$a=1
$b=6
```

Please keep in mind that I do not have any issue with the query itself,  I get the expected results,  the problem is at **PHP** level.  **PHP** 5.3+ on Debian 6.0.

Actually this is my query:

```
$query=$dbh->prepare("SELECT user_variable, variable_value FROM table where id_user=? ");
$query->execute(array($id_user));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, [extract()](https://www.php.net/extract) is what you're looking for.

Comment: this will only work if the query results are pulled into an associative array